# Every day test for Xampp

Tags: php, notifications, xampp

I am currently developing an aplication based on Xampp. This will have to send maximum 1 email per day to a user to notify him about something. That something is based on a specifict test, such as if a set date in a table is past the current day. Is there a way to generate this test every day, or what is a suitable solution for this problem?

Comment: That's achieved by a contrab and a a php (or py, or bash, etc..) script; You make the contrab call the script every X time on a day and that script is ran and checks for everything and sends (or not) the email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think that you run `xampp` u use a windows maschine. therefor use the `windows task scheduler` and point to your `xampp/php/php.exe` and execute this file. in your windows scheduler you can set the options to run this task every day.

`C:\xampp\php.exe -f "C:\PHP Scripts\script.php"`

http://php.net/manual/de/install.windows.commandline.php

Comment: As I founded out you can even run the task while no one is logged in if you set the proper setting. This is usefull if you instal xampp as a service witch starts even if there is no loged account.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Windows, so you must use windows scheduler to do this
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/schedule-task
Xampp won't be able to run cron job